# Updating Inventory table from Sales table

Tags: sql, oracle

Hey all so I have 2 tables.

Inventory:

```
ITEMNAME | QUANTITY
---------|---------
ITEM A   |       200
ITEM B   |       310
ITEM C   |       255
ITEM D   |       115
```

Sales:

```
SALENO | QUANTITY | ITEMNAME
-------|----------|---------
1001   |         5|   ITEM A
1002   |       100|   ITEM X
1003   |         1|   ITEM C
1004   |        20|   ITEM B
```

What I am having trouble with is updating my Inventory QUANTITY values with specific SALENOs.

Lets say I have already UPDATED my Inventory up to SALENO 1002.

So SALENO 1003 & 1004 are new sales and so I only need to subtract from my Inventory QUANTITY those 2 specific orders. How can I achieve this?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There is no reason to SHOUT your questions here. It won't get you answers any more quickly, and it's extremely rude. Please don't do so. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry.. I normally don't fully capitalize titles of questions.. forgot caps was on from typing SQL.

Answer (score 2):

To write an update statement with more than one table in Oracle, you need to use syntax like this:

```
UPDATE Inventory SET 
Inventory.QUANTITY = Inventory.QUANTITY - (SELECT 
  Sales.QUANTITY
  FROM Sales 
  WHERE 
  Sales.ITEMNAME = Inventory.ITEMNAME AND
  Sales.SALENO IN (1003, 1004)
)
WHERE
(Inventory.ITEMNAME IN 
    (
      SELECT 
      s.ITEMNAME 
      FROM SALES s 
      WHERE 
      s.SALENO IN (1003, 1004)
    )
)
```

Working sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0515/1/1)

Comment: Running this query updated all rows. It did work for those that were specified (1003, 1004). However it put `(null)` value in for the others. Any idea why this may be?

Comment: ok, I have changed the update statement. I have put the where clause against the Inventory table - so that it will only update Inventory records where the ItemName is the same as an ItemName from Sales with a Sale No of 1003 or 1004.

Comment: This new update statement returned to me: `SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

Comment: ok, I have added back in the Sales.SALENO IN (1003, 1004) clause into the first subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Could the following work?

```
UPDATE Inventory, Sales
SET Inventory.QUANTITY = Inventory.QUANTITY - Sales.QUANTITY
WHERE Inventory.ITEMNAME = Sales.ITEMNAME
   AND Sales.SALENO IN (1003, 1004)
```

Comment: Currently driving home, will test this ASAP (~15min) and let you know!

Comment: I certainly hope you're testing a self-driving car.

Comment: I was not driving :) I suppose I should have said I am being driven home.

Comment: The following query does not work. `SQL Error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword 00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword` I believe this is because there are 2 tables in the UPDATE clause